# Why is my Spark Mlib ALS collaborative filtering training model so slow?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, collaborative-filtering

I currently use the ALS collaborative filtering method for a content recommendation system in my App. It seems to work fine and the prediction part is quick but the training model part takes over 20 seconds. I need it to be at least 1 second or less, since i need almost real time recommendations. I currently use a spark cluster with 3 machines, each nodes has 17GB. I also use datastax but that shouldn't have any influence.

I don't really know why and how to improve this? Happy for any suggestions, thanks.

Here is the basic spark code:

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating

# Load and parse the data
data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/als/test.data")
ratings = data.map(lambda l: l.split(','))\
    .map(lambda l: Rating(int(l[0]), int(l[1]), float(l[2])))
```

This part takes over 20 seconds but should only take less then 1.

```
# Build the recommendation model using Alternating Least Squares
rank = 10
numIterations = 10
model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations)

# Evaluate the model on training data
testdata = ratings.map(lambda p: (p[0], p[1]))
predictions = model.predictAll(testdata).map(lambda r: ((r[0], r[1]), r[2]))
ratesAndPreds = ratings.map(lambda r: ((r[0], r[1]), r[2])).join(predictions)
MSE = ratesAndPreds.map(lambda r: (r[1][0] - r[1][1])**2).mean()
print("Mean Squared Error = " + str(MSE))

# Save and load model
model.save(sc, "target/tmp/myCollaborativeFilter")
sameModel = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, "target/tmp/myCollaborativeFilter")
```

Comment: So you think that 20 seconds is a lot ? How much data do you have ?

Comment: I didn't even add 100 user behavior data and it's already this slow. Any thoughts why? If I don't update it in less than 1 second I won't have any recommendations for new users since they don't occur in the model. Do you know what I mean? But maybe my logic is flawed. Thanks

Comment: Do you really have to retrain your model every time new data comes in? That would really be inefficient in the long run. What I suggest is to perform an overall update to the model that runs for a long time whenever you have collected enough data. However, as an intermediate step, you should only do `model.predict` for new data.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons why it may take time is because of RDDs. For RDDs, there is no specific structure/schema. Hence those tend to be a little slow. when ALS.train() is called, Some operations such as flatmap, count, map which happens behind the scenes on RDD will have to consider nested structures, hence the slowness.

Instead, you can try the same using Dataframes instead of RDDs. Dataframe operations are optimal, since the schema/types are known. But for ALS to work on dataframes, you have to import ALS from "ml.recommendation". I too had the same problem and when I tried with dataframes instead of RDDs, it worked very well.

You can also try out checkpointing when your data becomes quite big.